# Complex Excel Formula

Tags: vba, excel

I have what might be a strange formula I need to create in Excel and not sure how to accomplish this.

I have a value in one worksheet that I want to pull into another cell in a separate worksheet. This part is easy. What I want to do though is have a leader text before that content is pulled in (in the same cell). So far I think this is easy too. Now the complicated part. I want the leader text to be one color and weight and the text pulled in from worksheet 1 to be a different color and weight.

Any thoughts? So it might look like this:

**From:** Brian's Business

Where "From:" is Red and Bold and "Brian's Business" is Black and normal weight.

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this task?

Thanks in advance.

Brian

Comment: Also, if the cell contains a formula the formatting will not be available to each character.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did with the VBA macro, you can do the same thing and adopt it to your needs

```
Sub Macro1()
    Range("F28").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "hjkljhklhjkl : ddfff"
    With ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=0).Font
        .Name = "Arial"
        .FontStyle = "Regular"
        .Size = 10
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .Color = -16777216
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontNone
    End With
    With ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=7).Font
        .Name = "Arial"
        .FontStyle = "Bold"
        .Size = 10
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .Color = -16776961
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontNone
    End With
    With ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=8, Length:=2).Font
        .Name = "Arial"
        .FontStyle = "Regular"
        .Size = 10
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .Color = -16777216
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontNone
    End With
    With ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=10, Length:=11).Font
        .Name = "Arial"
        .FontStyle = "Regular"
        .Size = 10
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontNone
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Macro recorder to the rescue.

Comment: Thank you. So I imported this macro and studied and see what is happening with it. What I cannot quite figure out is how I can pull in text from another worksheet, example "ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "'data-table'!B19"" doesn't seem to work. Thoughts? And Thank you!

Comment: One other question now that I'm thinking through presentation options. Is there a way to use this macro to insert the data into a shape? For example, I insert a square shape, go to the formula bar and enter a formula into the shape. I name the object "shape1". Any thoughts on how to use this macro to insert the text into the shape vs. a field?

Comment: For your first comment/question, there are two parts: first, you need to add an "=" sign before "data-table" because you are telling Excel that you want to actually put a formula in the cell and secondly, you need to escape any double quote inside the formula with two double quotes ("").  Personally, if you don't need it to be a formula, I would simply use: ActiveCell = Sheets("data-table").cells(19,2)

Comment: And for your second question, once again, use the Macro Recorder (or ask this as another question, not as a comment because we can't format code inside comments).  The following two comments (taken as one macro) will insert a shape and add text to it

Comment: ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 231, 48, 72, 72).Select

Comment: Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Text in here"

Comment: @Michael, this method will not work if your cell contains a formula.

Comment: Thank you Michael, I will implement this today and see how it works. I greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: @jbarker2160 the original comment only asked for text, so I only gave text.  If you want to keep it as a formula, you need to make sure your FORMULA is correct for your REFERENCE STYLE.  The above equation mixes R1C1 style with A1 style, which is incompatible.  Simply add "Application.ReferenceStyle = xlA1" to the beginning of the macro to switch to A1 and then remove the R1C1 at the end of the FORMULA, add an equal sign and remove the single quotes: ActiveCell.Formula = "=data-table!B19"

Comment: @Michael, he stated that he's going to be adding leader text to the value of a cell on another page using a formula (presumably concatenate).  If he uses a formula (as was stated in the question) he will not be able to access individual characters.  If you don't believe it then try it for yourself.